# Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException - Target class [CommandMakeCommand] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Using Laravel 8.75 and trying to upgrade to php 8.1 in composer.json to "php": "^8.1" and receive the error of Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException - Target class [CommandMakeCommand] does not exist.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. 
Use symfony/mailer instead.
Generating optimized autoload files
 
Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
@php artisan package:discover --ansi

Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

Target class [CommandMakeCommand] does not exist.

at
```

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:879

```
875▕
876▕         try {
877▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
878▕         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
879▕             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
880▕         }
881▕
882▕         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
883▕         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

  +13 vendor frames
 14  artisan:37
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload- 
dump event returned with error code 1
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?  Keep in mind that Laravel 8.75 is not the latest version, so maybe updating could already help?

Answer (score 19):

i also had same problem, in my case nwidart/laravel-modules package upgraded to 8.3 version, i downgraded to 8.2 version and problem solved

Comment: I am also getting same issue on  few application on laravel 8 since last 2 days and still it is not fixed.  I also have  nwidart/laravel-modules package and it is 8.2 and has not upgraded , I am using laravel 8.40. any one have idea about it ?

Comment: remove composer.lock and vendor folder (maybe laravel-modules upgreaded in composer.lock file), and in composer.json fix laravel-modules to 8.2, "nwidart/laravel-modules": "8.2",

Comment: Downgrading to 8.2 worked for me as well.

Comment: Yes, replaced ^8.2 to 8.2 in composer.json file and ran composer update. Fixed the issue, thanks @Farhad!

Answer (score 9):

see here: https://docs.laravelmodules.com/v9/introduction

If you have an existing config file, and you get an error:

`Target class [CommandMakeCommand] does not exist`

Then the config file will need updating first import the commands class:

`use Nwidart\Modules\Commands;`

Next replace the commands array with:

```
'commands' => [
    Commands\CommandMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\ComponentClassMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\ComponentViewMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\ControllerMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\DisableCommand::class,
    Commands\DumpCommand::class,
    Commands\EnableCommand::class,
    Commands\EventMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\JobMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\ListenerMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\MailMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\MiddlewareMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\NotificationMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\ProviderMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\RouteProviderMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\InstallCommand::class,
    Commands\ListCommand::class,
    Commands\ModuleDeleteCommand::class,
    Commands\ModuleMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\FactoryMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\PolicyMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\RequestMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\RuleMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\MigrateCommand::class,
    Commands\MigrateRefreshCommand::class,
    Commands\MigrateResetCommand::class,
    Commands\MigrateRollbackCommand::class,
    Commands\MigrateStatusCommand::class,
    Commands\MigrationMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\ModelMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\PublishCommand::class,
    Commands\PublishConfigurationCommand::class,
    Commands\PublishMigrationCommand::class,
    Commands\PublishTranslationCommand::class,
    Commands\SeedCommand::class,
    Commands\SeedMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\SetupCommand::class,
    Commands\UnUseCommand::class,
    Commands\UpdateCommand::class,
    Commands\UseCommand::class,
    Commands\ResourceMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\TestMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\LaravelModulesV6Migrator::class,
],
```

Comment: Please share more details. `Nwidart`  does not sound like a namespace that all applications should have

Comment: change modules.php in your config folder

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your answer by editing it. What exactly should be changed?

Comment: change your ``commands`` property in modules.php config file

Comment: Please add **all clarification** to your answer by editing it

Answer (score 7):

Just add this line:

```php
use Nwidart\Modules\Commands\CommandMakeCommand;
```

in first of `config/modules.php` file as a `namespace`

Above namespace will resolve only commandMakeCommand issue, but if you want to set all command namespace then you need to add the namespace at the top.

```
namespace Nwidart\Modules\Commands;
```

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps (backup your project first):

1. First remove nwidart/laravel-modules by running: `composer remove nwidart/laravel-modules`
2. Then remove `config/modules.php` by deleting it.
3. Reinstall nwidart/laravel-modules by running: `composer require nwidart/laravel-modules`

Source:
[Githubhot, the answer by mohamedsharaf](https://githubhot.com/repo/nWidart/laravel-modules/issues/1355)

Answer (score 3):

If someone is still looking for the answer so follow these steps

As mentioned in this link see here: https://docs.laravelmodules.com/v9/introduction

If you have an existing config file, and you get an error:

```
Target class [CommandMakeCommand] does not exist
```

Then the config file will need updating first import the commands class, and in your config folder update the `modules.php` file includes

```
use Nwidart\Modules\Commands;
```

Then replace the commands array with: add `Commands\` before each value or simple copy and replace the array

```
 'commands' => [
    Commands\CommandMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\ComponentClassMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\ComponentViewMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\ControllerMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\DisableCommand::class,
    Commands\DumpCommand::class,
    Commands\EnableCommand::class,
    Commands\EventMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\JobMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\ListenerMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\MailMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\MiddlewareMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\NotificationMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\ProviderMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\RouteProviderMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\InstallCommand::class,
    Commands\ListCommand::class,
    Commands\ModuleDeleteCommand::class,
    Commands\ModuleMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\FactoryMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\PolicyMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\RequestMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\RuleMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\MigrateCommand::class,
    Commands\MigrateRefreshCommand::class,
    Commands\MigrateResetCommand::class,
    Commands\MigrateRollbackCommand::class,
    Commands\MigrateStatusCommand::class,
    Commands\MigrationMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\ModelMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\PublishCommand::class,
    Commands\PublishConfigurationCommand::class,
    Commands\PublishMigrationCommand::class,
    Commands\PublishTranslationCommand::class,
    Commands\SeedCommand::class,
    Commands\SeedMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\SetupCommand::class,
    Commands\UnUseCommand::class,
    Commands\UpdateCommand::class,
    Commands\UseCommand::class,
    Commands\ResourceMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\TestMakeCommand::class,
    Commands\LaravelModulesV6Migrator::class,
],
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to downgrade nwidart/laravel-modules version in composer.json file. Just change this line to the below line.

```
"nwidart/laravel-modules": "8.2.*"
```

Then delete composer.lock file and now, run this command.

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

in `config/modules` add name full path to command `Nwidart\Modules\Commands`

```
'commands' => [
    Nwidart\Modules\Commands\CommandMakeCommand::class
    ...
],
```

Answer (score -1):

This Is Not Related Routes Or Any Other Parts Of Your App ,
When You Cant Run Composer Update Or Artisan Commands
You Have Problem In Booting Laravel , In This Case :
Go To Your Config Folder Open Modules File And Check "Command" Key
My Problem Fixed By This Way !
Good Day !

Comment: Please share more details. How does checking any "command key" resolve the problem?

Comment: This Error Happened Because Commands That Located In Config/App/modules Can Not Resolved By Laravel So If You Recognised Them For Laravel The Problem Has Will Be Solved ! I Check It Just Today And It Fixed !

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. If Laravel cannot resolve commands in `Config/App/modules`, how does checking any "Command Key" resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

use complete path of the Target class

eg :

```
use App\Models\Company;
```

or

```
Route::resource('companies', App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController::class);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. The question itself doesn't mention `App\Models\Company` or any controller